How to read from refcursor inside a function/procedure in postgresql
Lets say I have 2 functions: get_emp_ids and get_emp_details on my employees table. The get_emp_ids function returns a refcursor containing the ids of the employees. This will be function that will be frequently called in other procedures/functions.
get_emp_ids is something like this:
open id_cursor for
 select id from employees where some_complex_logic based on input_parameters;

...
return id_cursor

get_emp_details will internally call get_emp_ids something like this:
select get_emp_ids(input_parameters, id_cursor);

open result_cursor for
 select name, age, manager, title from employees where id in id_cursor;

...
return result_cursor

What is the correct way to write the where conditionget_emp_details
PS - Both of the functions will have the same input parameters.
I have tried using FETCH AND other similar options but I am getting syntax error.
